# Every NPM module cause error

Tags: node.js, npm

everytime and in any project i try to install new NPM module it ends with error.
Is there a way how to completely disable node-gyp and do all actions throught node?

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\react\fetchingInReact-master\node_modules\ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(55,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v
100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Re
target solution". [C:\Users\Dan\Documents\react\fetchingInReact-master\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:235:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Dan\Documents\react\fetchingInReact-master\node_modules\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v10.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Currently i am using visual studio code and i have problem to install every package

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a different IDE e.g. Brackets or Sublime?

Comment: @rags2riches currently i am using NodeJS to develop react app. If i try to install package module throught CMD i have the same error, so i think its not about IDE

Comment: @JonasLochmann I think you know what's going on here, Is there a way how to uninstall node-gyp or how to not run all modules installations throught node-gyp?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install MS visual c++ build tool. you can install it firing below command

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

further, you can find stand along executable [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159)

Comment: For right this command i have used, to solve different problem, but caused this problem in above.  When I enter it into the console, It will install it all, but I still can not install the modules

Answer (score 0):

OK, so finally i have solved it!

1. I was uninstalled NodeJS
2. Deleted folder from C:\Program Files\nodejs
3. Install NodeJS